# get() returned more than one Post : return 2

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

i was trying to make like button for my django blog but i'm getting error while hitting like the error is get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!
 here is my code

## views.py

```
class PostLikeRedirect(RedirectView):

          def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
              obj = get_object_or_404(Post)
              url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
              user = self.request.user
              if user.is_authenticated():
                  obj.likes.add(user)
              return url_
```

## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True,related_name='post_likes')
     content = models.TextField()
     img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics',blank=True)
     time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('LoveTravel-Details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

## urls.py

```
path('blog/<int:pk>/like/', PostLikeRedirect.as_view(),name='Like'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line isn't filtering the posts, so it returns all of them

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Post)
```

You want to filter by the primary key, which you can fetch from **kwargs

```
def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=kwargs['pk'])
    ...
```

Comment: Remove the `()` from `if user.is_authenticated` - it has been a property since Django 1.10.

Comment: its worked thnks and i import api adn its showing error again get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Comment: should i need to change urls.py,  path('blog/api/<int:pk>/like/', PostLikeApiToggle.as_view(),name='Like-Api-Toggle'),

Comment: Sorry, I can't fix multiple problems on a single thread. If you have a new problem, then please ask a new question. Show the code, and the *full traceback* of the error. Without the full traceback, we have to guess where the error is coming from.